# Problem with DNS

Tags: pi-3, dns

Can't connect to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) even being connected to the Internet.

I always need to change the DNS to `8.8.8.8` in `/etc/resolv.conf` but it changes automatically into `127.0.0.1` and then [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) do not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` file and add the following to the end:

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Don't edit `/etc/resolv.conf` since that file is generated automatically.

Answer (score 12):

I had the problem that my raspberry 3 couldn't connect to inet, but it had connection (no ping to google.com but it had ping to the ip address). So I figured it was a DNS problem. After a search I found this solution. Sorry, but I don't remember where, so I can't post the link.

It's true that /etc/resolv.conf is created at every reboot, so you lose the changes you make.

A solution is to create a file in /etc named resolv.conf.head

```
sudo nano resolv.conf.head
```

and then put there the lines with the dns servers you want. For example, for google and OpenDns:

```
#Google DNS
nameserver 8.8.8.8

#OpenDns Servers
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

The lines you write in this file are automatically added to resolv.conf when it is generated.